# Delays for each thread in Ultimate Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have thread group of 10 threads.

And I see that all 10 threads start at the same time, therefore create unlikely huge load for first web request at the same time.

I want to randomize start times somehow. For example, add 5 seconds delay between thread starts: first thread starts, then 5 sec delay, then second thread starts, etc.

Is it possible with Ultimate Thread Group plug-in?

Comment: Why not add Uniform_Random_Timer http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer as the child of first sampler in the thread group. `This timer pauses each thread request for a random amount of time, with each time interval having the same probability of occurring. The total delay is the sum of the random value and the offset value.` I believe if you add as child it will hold only the parent sample.

Comment: @ManishSapariya - you should add that as an answer, as it is the correct solution, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add Uniform_Random_Timer jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/… as the child of first sampler in the thread group. This timer pauses each thread request for a random amount of time, with each time interval having the same probability of occurring. The total delay is the sum of the random value and the offset value. I believe if you add as child it will hold only the parent sample.